# matchAll Array for Group 1 Regex Matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, prototype, iterable

I'm trying to figure out a way to get all my Group 1 matches into an array without using a loop with `matchAll()`.

Here's what I have thus far, but it only yields the first match:

```
let str = "123ABC, 123ABC"
let results = str.matchAll(/123(ABC)/gi);
let [group1] = results;
alert(group1[1]);
```

How can I get the results of the `matchAll` into one single array? Aka:

```
// ABC, ABC
```

Comment: [It has been answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55059473/3832970)

Comment: I don't agree with you @ WiktorStribiżew, but I won't reopen if you close.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the op specifically wants to get only all group 1 matches without using a loop. Your link reference doesn't specifically show how to achieve that

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate, since the accepted answer here is literally the same as the example from the accepted answer there: `console.log(Array.from(matches, m => m[1])); // All match (Group 1) values`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.from` to convert results to array and perform map in one go:

```js
const matches = Array.from(results, match => match[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const str = "123ABC, 123ABC"

const results = Array.from(
  str.matchAll(/123(ABC)/gi), 
  ([_, g1]) => g1
)

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the `abc` part of the string then you don't need to use `matchAll` method. You can easily get the results you want simply using the **positive lookbehind** regex expresion with the `match` method.

```js
let str = "123ABC, 123ABC"
let results = str.match(/(?<=123)ABC/gi);
console.log(results)
// ["ABC","ABC"]
```

Here is some more information on these types of regex expressions [Lookahead and lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind)